# Laravel - migration error, nullable default?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In the migration I have the following line:

```
$table->date('end_date')->nullable()->change();
```

For some reason this dont work anymore when I moved from homestead to valet.

Error I get when I run the migration via console:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid
>   default value for 'end_date'

Comment: You probably have wrong type of column or data

Answer (score 1):

try `$table->date('end_date')->nullable()->default(null)->change();`. Maybe your db version doesn't accept `0000:00:00` zeros